# How can I copy data from one column to another and add text with it in phpMyAdmin?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

How can I copy data from one column to another and add text with it in phpMyAdmin?

```
UPDATE table_name SET column1=column2
```

this code to copy data from column1 to column2

```
UPDATE table_name SET column1='text'
```

and this to add text to column1 :D but how can i add column data and text in the same time 
`column1=column2+'text'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`concat()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat)

```
UPDATE table_name 
SET column1 = concat(column2 , 'text')
```

Comment: @Madhurbhaiya  thanks  for answer lifting ..   upvote somewhere

Comment: for the speed :D +1